# trying to get straight edges on an extrusion

Tags: edges, extrude, smooth

I'm looking for a way to get straight edges after I extrude a face and give it thickness to create a new mesh. When I do so it always comes out jagged on the edges. I'm basically trying to make an impression of the meshes surface to create a custom guide that fits the original mesh. [image]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.